# Getting this error; "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."

Tags: laravel

Basically, when I'm trying to create a new entry for my database, I get thrown this error. I've been true almost every other article on the matter but have yet to find the error/issue. My code is as such;

```
$userId = DB::table(\Config::get('constants.DB_MAIN_DATABASE') . '.users')->insertGetId(
[
  'email' => $input['email'],
  'name' => $input['name'],
  'mobile_no' => $input['mobile_no'],
  'interest' => $input['interest'] ? implode(',', $input['interest']) : null,
  'interest_other' => $input['interest_other'] ? $input['interest_other'] : null,
  'password' => bcrypt($input['password']),
  'verified' => 0,
  'admin' => 0,
  'token' => str_random(30),
  'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
]);
dd($userId);
```

Note that I can't even reach my dd. The values are as such;

```
$input['email'] = "Prawn@abc.com"
$input['name'] = "Udh N"
$input['mobile_no'] = "0123456789"
$input['interest'] = "1"
$input['interest_other'] = "2"
$input['password'] = "password"
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: which line is it occurring on?

Comment: It says Response.php line 399? But I do not even have a response added into this..

Comment: can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: if you comment out both of those lines, do you get the same error?

Comment: It worked once i set `'interest'` and `'interest_other'` as null. but if i use the way that was shown above, it does not work. Odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using implode to a string.

```
implode(',', $input['interest'])
```

to fix this error set your string as array

```
implode(',', [$input['interest']])
```

Comment: thanks! that works, but i still don't get why the error is as above instead of stating type mismatch or something.